# Double value stored as zero in the database

Tags: java, postgresql

I have a table in my postgres database ie. student which has columns namely name marks1 marks2 where name is varchar(20), marks1 and marks2 is double precision data types.

I am using a prepared statement in a java class

```
PreparedStatement ps=con.preparestatement("insert into student values(?,?,?);
ps.setString(1,t.getUname());
ps.setDouble(2,t.getUmarks1());
ps.setDouble(3,t.getUmarks2());
status=ps.executeUpdate();
```

But when a double value is sent it says the above error mentioned in my question.

I have another class where the getters and setters are defined. That is as follows.

```
public class User {  
private String uname;
       private double umarks1,umarks2;  

public String getUname() {  
 return uname;  
}  

public void setUname(String uname) {  
 this.uname = uname;  
}  

public double getUmarks1() {  
 return umarks1;  
}  

public void setUmarks1(double umarks1) {  
 this.umarks1 = umarks1;  
}  

public double getUmarks2() {  
 return umarks2;  
}  

public void setUmarks2(double umarks2) {  
  this.umarks2 = umarks2;  
 }  

}
```

If i change the data type to double it saves a 0 in the database. I want to save a double value. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I would have thought the best way to do this is to change your Java class to reflect your data model

1) change `marks` field and getters/setters to double

2) change `PreparedStatement` to `setDouble`

see [setDouble](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setDouble%28int,%20double%29)

Comment: I did the same I changed the marks field to double and PreparedStatement to setDouble but a 0 is returned if I do so to the database

Comment: well show the code that you tried, not the code which is obviously wrong

Comment: So now there is no error?  Have you confirmed the values in a debugger?

Comment: Yup there is no error. The value is stored in the database but as zero.

Comment: Check the values before inserting.  Also I find it safer to specify the columns by name e.g. String insertTableSQL = "INSERT INTO DBUSER"
    + "(USER_ID, USERNAME, CREATED_BY, CREATED_DATE) VALUES"
    + "(?,?,?,?)";

Comment: ok right sir. Thank u. I will check the values before insertion by printing on the console. thanks for the safe tip.